# Como fazer a seguinte consulta sem usar INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

Tenho a tabela A com os seguintes campos:

```
ID | ID_PAIS_ENVIO | ID_PAIS_RECIBO
1  | 23            | 47
//...
```

Tenho a tabela B com os seguintes campos:

```
ID | NOME_PAIS
23 | Brasil
47 | Portugal
//...
```

Preciso de uma query que retorne o seguinte resultado:

```
ID | ID_PAIS_ENVIO | NOME_PAIS_ENVIO | ID_PAIS_RECIBO | NOME_PAIS_RECIBO
1  | 23            | Brasil          | 47             | Portugal
```

É possível obter o resultado acima sem fazer INNER JOIN 2 vezes na mesma query?

Comment: Qual é o problema em fazer dois JOINs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo a pergunta: Não. Você tem duas chaves diferentes e precisa de um JOIN para cada chave pra buscar a descrição da segunda tabela.

Qualquer solução diferente disso irá alterar o resultado da sua consulta, ou então solucionar fora do banco de dados (pela aplicação, gerando uma coleção de países e atribuindo a descrição).

Answer (score 5):

Sim, basta usar *aliases* diferentes para a tabela em cada `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    Envios.*,
    PaisEnvio.nome_pais AS nome_pais_envio,
    PaisRecibo.nome_pais AS nome_pais_recibo
FROM Envios
    INNER JOIN Paises AS PaisEnvio
    ON PaisEnvio.id = Envio.id_pais_envio
    INNER JOIN Paises AS PaisRecibo
    ON PaisRecibo.id = Envio.id_pais_recibo
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas veja, era isso que eu queria evitar, no fim do post pergunto se é possível sem fazer INNER JOIN 2 vezes, uma única consulta que retorna 2 linhas em apenas 1.

Comment: Ops, não percebi essa parte. Até é possível fazer um único JOIN, mas nesse caso você não conseguirá distinguir os países de envio e recebimento pelo próprio SQL. E terá duas linhas para cada envio no resultado.

Comment: A nível de performance, haveria algum impacto considerável?

Comment: Acredito que não, Filipe. Mas só testando pra dizer com certeza.

Answer (score 4):

Use a seguinte query:

```
SELECT PAIS_ENVIO.NOME_PAIS, PAIS_RECIBO.NOME_PAIS
FROM A
INNER JOIN B PAIS_ENVIO on A.ID_PAIS_ENVIO = B.ID
INNER JOIN B PAIS_RECIBO on A.ID_PAIS_RECIBO = B.ID
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas veja, era isso que eu queria evitar, no fim do post pergunto se é possível sem fazer INNER JOIN 2 vezes.

Comment: Entendi. Bati o olho no título e entendi que vc precisava do INNER JOIN. Você pode tentar com subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

```
set @entrada = 23;
set @saida = 47;

SELECT 
    e.id_pais as entrada, s.id_pais as saida
FROM
    tbl_pais s,
    tbl_pais e
WHERE (s.id_pais = @saida AND e.id_pais = @entrada);
```

Não saberia outra forma de fazer sem algum tipo de join... Valeuu! :D

Answer (score 2):

***Com Sub Query ou Sub Select:***

```
SELECT 
   TabelaA.ID, 
   TabelaA.ID_PAIS_ENVIO, 
   (SELECT TabelaB.NOME_PAIS FROM TabelaB WHERE TabelaB.ID=TabelaA.ID_PAIS_ENVIO) AS NOME_PAIS_ENVIO,
   TabelaA.ID_PAIS_RECIBO,
   (SELECT TabelaB.NOME_PAIS FROM TabelaB WHERE TabelaB.ID=TabelaA.ID_PAIS_RECIBO) AS NOME_PAIS_RECIBO 
FROM TabelaA
```

*Obs:* **A pergunta é sem JOIN, mas, é recomendável o uso do JOIN por ser mais rápido, já o Sub-Select pode degradar consideravelmente a sua pesquisa.**

*Referencia:*

- [Trabalhando com Subquery’s](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/253/sql-server/trabalhando-com-subquerys/)

Answer (score 0):

Tem como fazer sem join ligando as tabelas no WHERE .

```
   SELECT a.id
     , a.id_pais_envio
     , b_e.nome_pais as nome_pais_envio
     , a.id_pais_recibo
     , b_r.nome_pais as nome_pais_recibo

  FROM tabelaA as a
     , tabelaB as b_e
     , tabelaB as b_r

 WHERE a.id_pais_envio = b_e.id
   AND a.id_pais_recibo = b_r.id
```